# Total novice: How do I install this driver after these instructions?

Tags: wireless, drivers, lubuntu, tar

As my first question, and as a totally new user of Lubuntu, I really need to know how to install the wifi driver on my **emachines em250 netbook**. I installed Lubuntu on it, and everything works fine except the wifi which doesn't seem to exist.

So after many, many hours of searching and reading, I came upon these instructions at this link:

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1421768

I tried to post the text here for you to read, but it wouldn't work without this site changing it for some reason.

---

Now the thing is, almost all of that description is greek to me. It assumes that you know a bunch of stuff about Lubuntu already. Is there anyone out there kind enough to interpret these descriptions for me, step by step, so that I can try to install the driver. After all, what is a netbook without wifi.

EDIT:

My system tells me it's "Ubuntu 13.10".

- After running some commands, I got this info about my system:

  ```
  01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
  [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
  ```

and

```
Lo no wireless extensions.

eth0 no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the make and model of your card. Also, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) run these commands, and post their output here: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` and `sudo iwconfig`. That's a four year old thread, I doubt the instructions are still relevant. Oh, and about why your text was changed, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: The exact solution depends on your Ubuntu version. Please edit your question to add the result of: lsb_release -d Thanks.

Comment: It says it's "Ubuntu 13.10".